# Isn't layoutSubviews supposed to get called once per frame only?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I thought that `view.layoutSubviews()` gets called once per frame to avoid computing the layout too many times. That's the whole reason for the existence of `view.setNeedsLayout()`. Such that you may call `view.setNeedsLayout()` many times, including many times per frame, but it only gets computed once. That's why you also have a second method, `view.layoutIfNeeded()` which computes the layout immediately.

This is not what seems to happen here:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

var time = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .cyan


    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.001, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        print("hello")
    }

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let newDate = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    print("Layout called at time: \(newDate - time)")
    time = newDate
}
```

}

What happens here is "Layout called at time..." get called at 0.001 intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not once per frame, it's once per iteration of the run-loop. Since your app isn't really doing anything, this will be about as fast as your interval.